# R Shiny - selectizeInput ignore clearing the text area

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

I have a selectizeInput with a lot of options (more than 500) that updates a plot in my shiny application. The plot is displaying the data correctly for each choice.

The problem that I am having is: when the user clears the selectize text area to write down what he/she is looking for, the selectizeInput is sending an update to the plot with an empty string `""`.

Is there a way to configure the selectize to ignore when the text area is cleared or do I have to keep tabs on its last state and save it in a global variable?

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
   updateSelectizeInput(session, 'foo', choices = my.choices, server = TRUE)
   output[['my.plot']] <- renderPlotly(plot_data(input))
}

plot_data <- function(input) {
   plot <- my.data %>%
      filter(z == input[['foo']]) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point()

   ggplotly(plot)
}
```

Comment: add `req(input$foo)` as the first line of your plot function

Comment: it no longer throws an error, but now the plot disappears

Comment: What do you want to show when the input is blank?

Comment: while the user does not change the selected input, the previous one should be visible